# Cauchy Integral Formula Question.

Tags: complex-analysis

I found the following question, and I dont seem to understand the work involved.

$\int \frac{e^z + z}{z - 2} dz$. Here $f(z) = e^z + z$ and $z_{0} = 2$. Okay that makes sense to me.

Then $f(z_{0}) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int\limits_{C} \frac{e^z + 2}{z - 2}dz \Rightarrow \int\limits_{C} \frac{e^z + z}{z - 2}dz = 2 \pi i(e^2 + 2)$.

Now i know the formula for $f(z_{0})$ but I don't understand how it got us to the answer. Could someone explain it to me. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Whoop. According to what I am looking at, $C$ just seems to be a circle which contains $z_{0}$

Comment: Are you asking how/why the Cauchy integral formula works?

Comment: No. I am asking how it works.

Comment: Your reply is a bit confusing. Here is the intuition: If you consider a power series expansion for an analytic $f$ around $z=a$, you have $f(z) = \sum_k a_k (z-a)^k$. If you divide by $z-a$ and swap order of integration and summation, only one term in the integration is non-zero; the one corresponding to $k=0$. Hence the integral value is $2 \pi i a_0$. Since $a_0 = f(a)$, this gives the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy integral formula states that if $f$ is analytic in an open set containing the disc $D$ which has $C$ as its boundary, then

$$
f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz
$$ 
If we multiply both sides by $2\pi i$, we obtain

$$
\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz=2\pi if(z_0)
$$

In your case, $f(z)=e^z+z$, $z_0=2$, and so $f(z_0)=e^2+2$.  So using the second formula, we obtain the result you stated,

$$
\oint_C \frac{e^z+z}{z-2}=2\pi i f(2)=2\pi i(e^2+2)
$$

Does this help?

Comment: Okay that makes really good sense. Now what if we have a case where their are $2$ points that could be $z_{0}$? For example consider, $\int\limits_{|z+1| = 2}\frac{z^2}{4 - z^2}dz$. How do I know which one to use?

Comment: You can't just apply the formula in this case, use partial fraction expansion first.

Comment: Factoring the bottom yields, $(2 + z)(2 - z)$. Couldnt I just use $z_{0} = -2$ since it lies in the circle and let $\frac{z^2}{2-z}$ be my $f(z)$?

Comment: @DanielSmith correct, you could factor the bottom and use $z_0=-2$ and $f(z)=z^2/(2-z)$ if you take the circle $\vert z+1\vert=2$.